# pandas group by with different calculations (row level and column level)

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation-framework

I have the following dataframe:

| Customer ID | Country | Is True |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | China | 1 |
| 124 | China | 1 |
| 125 | Colombia | 0 |
| 126 | Bangladesh | 0 |
| 127 | Bangladesh | 1 |
| 128 | China | 0 |
| 129 | Colombia | 0 |
| 130 | Bangladesh | 0 |
| 131 | Bangladesh | 0 |
| 132 | China | 1 |

I want to create something like pivot that will give me:

| Country | Count Customers | % of population | # True | True Ratio (of Country) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bangladesh | 4 | 40% | 1 | 25% |
| China | 4 | 40% | 3 | 75% |
| Colombia | 2 | 20% | 0 | 0% |

Note: The second column is calculated on the column level- it's the ratio of the specific country out of the entire population (I have 4 customers from China out of 10, that's 40%).
The true ratio is on the row level: within China I have 1 'True' which is 25% of all (4) China.
I managed to add the count calculations:

```
Country = df.groupby('Country').agg(Count Customers = ('CustomerID', 'count'), TrueCount = ('is True','sum'))
```

How do I add the 2 ratios?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: tried to edit, it's now worse... so strange that you can't copy a table from excel

Comment: You have to add | -- | -- | between de headers and the values to get a nice table

Comment: @Hana Try to read excel using pandas into a data frame, df, and paste the output of `print(df)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Customer ID':range(123,133),
        'Country':['China', 'China', 'Colombia', 'Bangladesh', 'Bangladesh', 'China', 'Colombia', 'Bangladesh', 'Bangladesh', 'China'],
        'is True':[1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
    }
)
```

First you can use the groupby to create your first two columns (Count Customers & #True). Then you can use these values to create the other two columns:

```
agg_df = df.groupby('Country').agg(
        CountCustomers=('Customer ID', 'count'),
        TrueCount=('is True','sum')
    )
agg_df['% of population'] = agg_df['CountCustomers'] / agg_df['CountCustomers'].sum()
agg_df['True Ratio (of Country)'] = agg_df['TrueCount'] / agg_df['CountCustomers']
```

Result:

```
            'CountCustomers'    'TrueCount' '% of population'   'True Ratio (of Country)'
Country             
Bangladesh  4                   1           0.4                 0.25
China       4                   3           0.4                 0.75
Colombia    2                   0           0.2                 0.00
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul, the 'True Ratio (of Country' is not what I need, though it happens to give the right result in this dataset. You basically calculate it on the column level, like the % of population', while I need it on the row level. so in Bangladesh the calculation is 1/4, in China 3/4 and in Colombia it's 0/2. The The first calculation is indeed what I need. Thanks!

Comment: But thanks to your answer, I figured it: agg_df['True Ratio (of Country'] = agg_df['TrueCount'] / agg_df['CountCustomers']     Thanks! if you edit the answer I will accept it

Comment: Changed it, good to see you figured it out :)